# order-isomorphism can send chain to other chain

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

exercise 7.20 in Goldrei:

> Let $a_1<\cdots<a_n,c_1<\cdots<c_n$ be rationals. Show that there is an order-isomorphism $f:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\forall i: f(a_i)=c_i$.

for $n=1$ we can take a translation, for $n=2$ we may take a linear polynomial $c_1+\frac{x-a_1}{a_2-a_1}(c_2-c_1)$. but for $n>2$ we cannot find a linear polynomial.
The theorem is intuitively clear, since we can stretch the interval $[a_1,a_n]$ appropriately. How can it be justified formally?

Comment: Just make it piecewise linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OUTLINE:**

The simplest way to prove this would be by induction on $n$.

For $n=1$ this is obvious, $f(x)=x+(c_1-a_1)$ is an automorphism of $\Bbb Q$ mapping $a_1$ to $c_1$.

Now suppose this is true for $n$, and take $(n+1)$-tuples $a_i,c_i$. Then there is an automorphism of $\Bbb Q$ mapping $a_i$ to $c_i$ for $i\leq n$, call it $F$. Now find a way to "cut and paste" isomorphism on the domain after $a_n$, and define $f$ as wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way, given what you've said, is just to use a piecewise linear function.

Maybe it's worth knowing that any two linearly ordered sets are order-isomrophic that satisfy the following:

- They are densely ordered, i.e. between any two elements there is another; and
- They are unbounded, i.e. no max or min; and
- They are countable.

Thus, for example, there is an order isomorphism between the rational numbers and the real algebraic numbers.  Or the binary rationals (i.e. rationals whose denominator is a power of $2$). Google the term "Cantor's back-and-forth method" and you'll find a proof.

Comment: Your solution does more than Asaf's, since it also proves it for some countably infinite chains, right? The chain just has to be 'discrete' in some sense. (And then this also shows that there are $\aleph$ order automorphisms on $\mathbb{Q}$)

Comment: It does apply to some countably infinite linearly ordered sets.  Of course, just what "'discrete' in some sense" means is problematic.  I don't know which cardinality you have in mind where you write $\aleph$.  I think the set of order-isomorphisms from $\mathbb Q$ to itself is uncountable.